# Call Write-Verbose from C#

Tags: powershell

I load an "inline-type" in PowerShell like so:

```
$source = " some c# here "
$type = Add-Type -TypeDefinition $source -PassThru
$myvar = [MyClass]::new()
$myvar.Do()
```

How to call `Write-Verbose` from within the C# snippet, i.e., from the source in `$source`?

I only find examples on the Internet which perform WriteVerbose calls if the C# code contains a Cmdlet - which it does not in my case. Also I can find code how to call cmdlets in general, however, I don't want to create a new runspace, is there maybe any way to get the *current* runspace?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, it is possible to pass a delegate to the C# code like so:

```
$writeVerboseDelegate = [Action[string]]{param($s) Write-Verbose $s; }
...
$myvar = [MyClass]::new($writeVerboseDelegate)
```